# How do I call a Kusto function with multiple params on each row of a table

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

I have the Kusto function, which will take a few parameters and return a scalar output. I want to call this on each row of a table.

```
function = test_data(since:datetime) {

   // perform some operations and return scalar results;
   let result = <sometable>
   let scalar_data = toscalar(result);
   print(scalar_events);

}
```

I want to call this on each row of a table:

When I tried this:

```
let result_data = datatable(since:datetime)
[
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:14.5162522Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
];
result_data
| extend data = test_data(since);
```

I got the below error:

> Error
>
> Semantic error: Tabular expression is not expected in the current
> context
>
> clientRequestId:

When I tried using toscalar as follows the column was not visible.

```
let result_data = datatable(since:datetime)
[
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:14.5162522Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
];
result_data
| extend data = toscalar(test_data(since));
```

Error:

> Error
>
> Semantic error: 'toscalar' operator: Failed to resolve table or
> scalar expression named 'since'
>
> clientRequestId:

When I passs static datetime, It works fine.

```
let result_data = datatable(since:datetime)
[
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:14.5162522Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
];
result_data
| extend data = toscalar(test_data(datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:14.5162522Z)));
```

How do I call a Kusto function on each row of a table? I have multiple params to pass here. For example, I am passing one param (Since)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

**`Note:`**
If you want to use **`toscalar()`**,  it can only be used on a single expression but not on column, this is a limitation as per [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction):

> Returns a scalar constant value of the evaluated expression.
> [image]

Below is the **`KQL Query`** which worked for me and I have used **`tostring()`** on each row in a table:

```
let x = (since:datetime)
{
tostring(since)
};
let result_data = datatable(since1:datetime)
[
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:14.5162522Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
  datetime(2023-09-20T18:37:29.2246502Z),   
];
result_data
| extend data = x(since1);
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WPywrCQAxF9/mKLDtgy0z6sO3gX7hSRKoNMjBW6EQoqP9upRW6cucqXHLuheNZcMANRsF1Z67bRljclRU8QG5BetddppeClwU/0j2Hu5fjSDZj73OkOXmeKLNY2APiN0WkKY11FZPemrJO17XJktwUlBPt1AoRf8JUJURZkev/wwcLC0N4Ig/CXYuz7zB7KvsGLqhLADoBAAA=)

Comment: Thank you, So there is no way to call a function on each rows in kusto, either we can use join or we should pass scalar input which will contain entire table in scalar format?

Comment: Yes, you should pass a scalar input as toscalar is not possible on whole column.